# Trying to understand the general scheme of how real-time audio signal processing works on embedded system

Tags: digital, arm

I played around with many microcontrollers before but never had a chance to do any kind of signal processing.

I'm trying to learn how to implement digital signal processing algorithms on the microcontrollers, but before the actual implementation of the algorithm I'm trying to understand the high-level overview of the whole signal processing chain.

If I use an audio example, my current understanding of the chain is like below.

The DSP algorithm condition is 16bit, 16khz sampling rate, and the algorithm filters high frequency using a simple IIR high pass filter.

1. System acquires sound data through a microphone (digital microphone, 16bit, 16khz)
2. Digital audio data is sent to the DSP block with a frame size of 10ms (160 samples)
3. DSP block fills up the buffer until a 1-second segment is filled.
4. When 1 second is filled, the audio algorithm will apply high pass filter and output the filtered data.
5. Audio DAC reads in the data and plays the media.

My current confusion this:

1. Who takes care of  filling up the audio data buffer part? Is there a microcontroller library, like in ARM, that covers data buffer management, or does the algorithm developer need to include a function that fills up the buffer?
2. How are the processed segmented audio data concatenated at the output? It feels like some kind of windowing is required. I'm assuming this is done by the DSP block.

If there are any good practical resources on implementing an audio signal processing library on the ARM cortex processor, it will be really appreciated.

Comment: My answer assumes the algorithm you described is *as is*, however I’ll emphasize the point Hilmar and Rbj made in their respective answers: steps 3 and 4 seem to introduce awfully long delay for an audio application… typically any delay over 10-15 ms  is a no-go

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> System acquires sound data through a microphone(Digital Mic, 16bit, 16khz)

Audio can come from all kind of sources. Could be a digital microphone with a PDM interface, could be an A/D converter (analog mic, line in, etc), could be a digital input (SPDIF, HDMI), could be a USB stream, could be a network connection, could be your local file system.

Depending on the source and what control you have over it, you need to figure out a "clocking scheme". Most common is that you have a single clock for both A/D and D/A or PDM (depending on what you have) which determines the rate at with the processor consumes and produces audio data. Any source or sink that can't be phase locked to this clock (like a USB connection, HDMI port), will need to go through a sample rate converter at some point.

> Digital audio data is sent to the DSP block and the frame size is 10ms (160 samples)

The frame size at which the DSP receives data depends a lot on the source. A local bus like I2S (A/D, D/A) send data continuously and you can typically choose frame size. That choice is typically a trade off between efficiency, latency, and memory foot print. It can be as short as 1 sample (Example: digital ANC headphone) or as long as is practical.

Other source (USB, network) determine the frame size themselves, the data comes in packets. Same goes for any encoded audio stream (MP3, AAC, Dolby Digital/Atmos etc). The frame size is determined by the decoder.

If the native frame size doesn't work, you can reframe the data to a more convenient size.

> DSP block fills up the buffer until a 1-second segment is filled.
> When 1second is filled, the audio algorithm will apply high pass filter and outputs the filtered data.

1s would be VERY large for an audio frame since it induces a latency of at least on second into the audio stream. In many applications this type of latency is unacceptable.

Many systems will simply process the audio at the same frame size they receive/sent it. You can't go faster and there is no real benefit in going slower.

> Audio DAC reads in the data and plays the media.

The output side has the same considerations as the input: there are all types of sinks with different requirements. Most DAC will receive a continuous data stream through an I2S port, so the DSP needs to "serialize" the frames.

> Who takes care of the filling up audio data buffer part? Is there a mcu library, like in arm, that covers data buffer management? Or does the algorithm developer need to include a function that fills up the buffer?

Most processors these days have dedicated HW for this. It's called DMA (Direct Memory Access). You can think of a DMA controller as a separate  processor that moves data between peripherals and internal memory. It will alert the main CPU, that a new buffer is available (or empty).

If push comes to shove can move the input (or output) sample by sample using the main CPU but that's very inefficient.

> how are the processed segmented audio data concatenated at the output? It feels like some kind of windowing is required. I'm assuming this is done by the DSP block.

That depends on the algorithm. Almost all algorithms including IIR filters have "state variables" which store intermediate data. The state variables need to be preserved between frames.

Comment: Good answer . .

Comment: Thanks for breaking down my questions into pieces for detailed answers. This is really helpful for imagining the process from a very practical point of view.

Answer (score 4):

1. **Buffer Management**:

   - In most embedded systems, buffer management is typically a
     combination of hardware and software functionalities. For a
     microcontroller like ARM Cortex, the Direct Memory Access (DMA)
     controller can be used to efficiently transfer audio data from the
     microphone to a buffer in memory without much CPU intervention.
   - Some microcontrollers have libraries or built-in support for
     handling these operations. For instance, ARM Cortex microcontrollers
     often have HAL (Hardware Abstraction Layer) libraries that simplify
     such tasks.
   - You may need to write code to
     initialize and manage these buffers, especially deciding when to
     start processing the data.
2. **Concatenation of Processed Segments**:

   - When processing audio in segments, care must be taken to avoid
     artifacts at the segment boundaries. This is where windowing
     comes into play. Techniques like overlap-add
     or overlap-save are used to concatenate segments smoothly.
   - The DSP block or the algorithm itself often handles this, ensuring
     continuity between processed segments.

#### Resources

- Textbooks, online courses, forums and online communities, youtube tutorials, the internet is your friend!
- [ARM Developer website](https://developer.arm.com/)
- [CMSIS-DSP Library](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/index.html): a rich collection of DSP functions optimized for ARM Cortex-M processors.

Comment: Good answer . .

Comment: overlap-add/overlap-save is the exact word that I was looking for! I'm not too familiar with the DSP domain, so I only assumed that there must be a windowing in between

Comment: overlap-add and overlap-save is ***not*** about the small blocks of samples (i.e. 32-sample block or 64-sample block), that I was talking about.  OLA and OLS are usually about doing efficient FIR filtering for a very long FIR, using the FFT.  But OLA is also a term that gets applied to techniques such as the phase vocoder.

Answer (score 2):

Two good answers.

I will add a small distinction about real-time DSP.

Non real time means processing a file of samples to another file and the processing time need not be smaller than the elapsed time to acquire the samples.  I.e. it may take more than 2 seconds of CPU time to process 2 seconds of samples data.  In the olden days (1980s) sometimes I would let my 68K Mac take an hour to process a short sound file of 30 or 60 seconds.   (Sound file wasn't so short for my 10 meg hard drive.)

Real-time processing means that the CPU can keep up with the samples as they're being acquired. So the CPU must be able to process 2 seconds of sound in less than 2 seconds of CPU time.  But there still could be a lotta delay.

***Live*** real-time DSP means that the processing delay is small enough that it can be perceived as immediate.  This is what happens in stomp boxes and rack-mounted DSP products.  It can also happen in your computer if some care is taken about buffering and the size of blocks of samples.

Now double-buffering is most often used for efficiency purposes.  This means the input block that is being processed was acquired in the *previous* block time and the results of processing goes into a block that will be outputted in the *following* block time.  This means there are 2 block times of delay.

To do this live, your block size must be small enough so that the throughput delay is tolerable.  In practice, we usually don't want our block size to exceed 32 or 64 samples.  At $f_\mathrm{s}$ = 48 kHz, that would be 1.333 or 2.666 ms, respectively.

Now these samples are coming in and going out at the same time as your processing.  That means you must either DMA the sample I/O or use an interrupt handler that is hooked up to the device where the samples are coming or going.

So, if you're polling, you watch the DMA buffer pointers until they have moved by 32 or 64 samples (assuming mono or 1 channel).  Then do some ping-ponging and start processing a block of samples.  To be real time, you must finish your sample processing (that is, you must compute your 32 or 64 output samples) before the next time your I/O input buffer fills again.

If you're not polling, either your DMA mechanism must understand that it filled the buffer and initiate an interrupt to process the samples, or if you don't have DMA, then your sample interrupt handler needs to count samples and know that the buffer was filled, to flag the system to start processing a block.

Comment: Good addition!!

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I can make a simple audio processing algorithm for saved audio data on python/MATLAB, but I couldn't wrap my head around continuous audio data processing. I think I made some steps toward live real-time processing today.

Comment: I mean, you're gonna need some gear to do real-time audio processing.  It's gotta be some CPU or DSP hooked up to an A/D and D/A.  You may need to code that board in the assembly language of the processor or, maybe, in C.  I don't think you'll be doing real-time DSP using python.